# How to define the "follow" relationship in laravel 5.2

Tags: php

Recently I use Laravel to define the 'follow' relationship between users. Here are the models:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function follows()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\User', 'followable');
    }
}

class Follow extends Model
{
    public function followable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

and the database for Follow is like this:

```
follows:
    - id:
    - user_id:
    - followable_id:
    - followable_type:
```

all the above are defined according to the examples which [Laravel documents](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) provides.

And now I can retrieve the user model like this:

```
$follow = Follow:find(1);
$user = $follow->followable;
```

But when I write code like this:

```
$followers = $user->follows;
```

I get errors:

```
Relationship method must return an object of type 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

here is my question:
Did I define the relationship of 'follow' right? and how can I fix the errors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function follows()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\User', 'followable');
    }
}
```

change in to

```
    class User extends Model
{
    public function follows()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Follow', 'followable');
    }
}
```

because your have given model name is incorrect.